# Let $A$ be a square matrix of order $n$ over $\mathbb{R}$ such that $A^2-3A+I_n=0_n$. Then $A^{-1}=3I_n-A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

Let $A$ be a square matrix of order $n$ over $\mathbb{R}$ such that $A^2-3A+I_n=0_n$. Then $A^{-1}=3I_n-A$.

The answer given is true.

Suppose $A^{-1}$ exists.
Then $A^{-1}(A^2-3A+I_n=A^{-1}(0_n)$ which implies $A-3I_n+A^{-1}=0_n$. So clearly, $A^{-1}=3I_n-A$.

But I can't show that the inverse of $A$ exists.

Comment: About the invertibility question alone: $A(A - 3 I_n) = -I_n$ so $\det A$ can not be $0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
3A-A^2 = I_n \implies (3I_n-A)A =I_n \implies 3I_n-A = A^{-1} 
$$

Also, $$
3A-A^2 = I_n \implies A(3I_n-A) =I_n \implies 3I_n-A = A^{-1}
$$

So the inverse of $A$ exists, it is both a right and left inverse.

Comment: Thanks, I keep on finding way to prove the determinant of $A$ to be nonzero which make me stuck.

Comment: @AlanWang The determinant is a multiplicative quantity. You can't use the determinant rule here because the determinant will not split across the negative sign, for example. Yes, the determinant will give invertibility as it is non-zero, but you cannot calculate the determinant of $A$ explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

For square matrices, a one-sided inverse is automatically the (unique) inverse. Let's exhibit a one-sided inverse... $3\,{\rm Id}_n-A$, say? We check: $$A(3\,{\rm Id}_n - A) = 3A - A^2 \stackrel{(\ast)}{=} {\rm Id}_n,$$where in $(\ast)$ we use the hypothesis.

Answer (score -1):

[image]

i guess this method's easier. Just expand the 'I'

Comment: You assume without proving that $A^{-1}$ exists (at the step where you replace $I_n$ by $A A^{-1}$ then again at the penultimate step), so this is not an answer to OP's question.

Comment: If A inverse doesnt exist then A would have infinite solution

Comment: Did you actually *read* the question in its entirety? It's plenty obvious that the OP *knew* how to solve it on the assumption that $A^{-1}$ exists, but had difficulty deriving the existence of $A^{-1}$ from the given condition.

Comment: Actually the question is baseless. Because if the inverse would not have existed then for than 1 matrix A(as other values can be present in the matrix A) would have satisfied the equality condition above. the comparing , we would have got contradiction.

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow what you are saying. If you have a good argument why $A^{-1}$ must in fact exist (and it's different from the already posted answers and comments) then please edit your answer and include that.